# From tick by tick data to Renko chart

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, finance, pandas

I've tick by tick data for Forex pairs

Here is a sample of `EURUSD/EURUSD-2012-06.csv`

```
EUR/USD,20120601 00:00:00.207,1.23618,1.2363
EUR/USD,20120601 00:00:00.209,1.23618,1.23631
EUR/USD,20120601 00:00:00.210,1.23618,1.23631
EUR/USD,20120601 00:00:00.211,1.23623,1.23631
EUR/USD,20120601 00:00:00.240,1.23623,1.23627
EUR/USD,20120601 00:00:00.423,1.23622,1.23627
EUR/USD,20120601 00:00:00.457,1.2362,1.23626
EUR/USD,20120601 00:00:01.537,1.2362,1.23625
EUR/USD,20120601 00:00:03.010,1.2362,1.23624
EUR/USD,20120601 00:00:03.012,1.2362,1.23625
```

Full tick data can be downloaded here
http://dl.free.fr/k4vVF7aOD

Columns are :

```
Symbol,Datetime,Bid,Ask
```

I would like to convert this tick by tick data to Renko chart
http://www.investopedia.com/terms/r/renkochart.asp

A parameter of the chart is candles height (close-open) : let's call it candle_height

I would like to use Python and Pandas library to achieve this task.

I've done a little part of the job... reading the tick by tick data file

I want to get data like

```
Id,Symbol,open_price,close_price
```

to be able to draw Renko

Id is the number of the candle

Price on candle will be based on Bid column.

Here is the code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.finance import candlestick

def candle_price_ref(price, candle_height):
  #return(int(price/candle_height)*candle_height)
  return(round(price/candle_height)*candle_height)

print("Reading CSV (please wait)")
df = pd.read_csv('test_EURUSD/EURUSD-2012-07.csv', names=['Symbol', 'Date_Time', 'Bid', 'Ask'], index_col=1)
print("End of reading")

df['Bid'] = df['Bid']
#candle_height = 0.0015
#candle_height = 0.0010
#candle_height = 0.0005
candle_height = 0.0001
#candle_height = 0.000001

price = df.ix[0]['Bid']
price_ref = candle_price_ref(price, candle_height)

ID = 0
#print("ID={0} price_ref={1}".format(ID, price_ref))

candle_price_open = []
candle_price_close = []

candle_price_open.append(price) # price ou price_ref
candle_price_close.append(price)

for i in range(len(df)):
  price = df.ix[i]['Bid']
  candle_price_close[ID] = price

  new_price_ref = candle_price_ref(price, candle_height)


  if new_price_ref!=price_ref:
    candle_price_close[ID]=new_price_ref
    price_ref = new_price_ref
    ID += 1
    candle_price_open.append(price_ref)
    candle_price_close.append(price_ref)

IDs=range(ID+1)
volume=np.zeros(ID+1)

a_price_open=np.array(candle_price_open)
a_price_close=np.array(candle_price_close)
b_green_candle = a_price_open < a_price_close
candle_price_low = np.where(b_green_candle, a_price_open, a_price_close)
candle_price_high = np.where(b_green_candle, a_price_close, a_price_open)

DOCHLV=zip(IDs, candle_price_open, candle_price_close, candle_price_high, candle_price_low, volume)

#print(DOCHLV)

fig = plt.figure()
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.1)
ax = fig.add_subplot(211)
df['Bid'].plot()
plt.title("Price graph")
ax = fig.add_subplot(212)
plt.title("Renko chart")
candlestick(ax, DOCHLV, width=0.6, colorup='g', colordown='r', alpha=1.0)
plt.show()
```

My problem is that what I'm doing here is not a real Renko chart for 2 reasons :

1. In a Renko chart you can't have a green candle and a red candle with same open price and close price (which is not the case in my code)...
2. Each candle must have a fixed height (with my code some candles have a height of 2 or 3 times candle_height... which is a problem !)

I'm looking for a quite fast algorithm, if possible a vectorized one (if it's possible) as tick data can be very big.

Comment: It would help if you created a small toy example, i.e. a pretend and simplified example. That way we might be able to provide some insight in how to code it.

Comment: That's what I did now (I edited my question) but I still have some problems as my code doesn't draw really a Renko plot

Answer (score 0):

```
 for i,row in enumerate(df.values):
     ID = i
     sym,timestamp,open_price,close_price = row
     print ID,sym,open_price,close_price
```

but I dont think I quite understand what you are trying to do...

Comment: that's not what I'm looking for... In fact Renko chart looks like candlestick chart but is different from it. With candlestick X-axis is time and Y-axis is price. But with Renko chart, Y-axis is price but X-axis is NOT time. A new candle appears each time price is moving more than "candle_height". So if price is moving less than candle_heigth, no new candle appears (even if it lasts a long time)